# How do I keep hex formatting when I get a hex value from an array in C?

Tags: c, gdb

I have an array like this:

```
   unsigned char arr[] = {0x55}; 
   unsigned char byte = arr[0];
```

And I want to have byte be the hex representation, just like it is in the array. 
But when I look at it in gdb, I keep getting that byte is 85 'U'. What has happened? Why don't I see 0x55, or even the binary representation 110111?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `p/x byte` to look at it.  `gdb` defaults to printing decimal unless you tell it otherwise.  You get the `'U'` because that's also part of the default for printing `char` type variables.

The value stored in the variable is binary - it's only how you're looking at it that is confusing you, I think.  `0x55`, `85`, and `'U'` are all different ways to interpret the same data.

Comment: Thanks. How can I see the binary representation?

Comment: Hex or octal are the closest you'll get in gdb - it doesn't have "binary" as an output format.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, GDB supports binary output with both the `x` and `p` commands.  user2057841, use `p/t byte` in this case.

Comment: Thanks Carl, p/t byte does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

GDB shows you the printable character corresponding to the `0x55` character code, because the value you have is of type `char`. To print it as hex, use this:

```
(gdb) p/x byte
```

Comment: Oh, ok thanks! I was using x/wt to print, and that wasn't printing the correct binary. I tried what you suggested and it does print 0x55. Does this mean it is in fact storing the correct values? How can I see the binary representation?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just joined the site yesterday and not sure how things work. I want to accept multiple answers, and up-vote too, but I don't have enough points to do that yet. I owe you one :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct [formatting flags on print](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_55.html):

Any I sure hope that your compiler makes 0x55 into 0x01010101 and nothing else.

Comment: I don't want to print yet, I just want to keep the hex or binary value so I can do shifts and other operations on it. Thanks

Comment: Right, so you are saying that "gdb shows me the variable as U or 85", which is the character and decimal representation of the binary number 0x01010101. In computers, ALL numbers are stored as binary. How they are displayed when you print them is what makes a difference to how we read them. Your number is the same, whether it's displayed as a U or 85 or 0x55 or 0125 (the last being octal) - that's JUST a matter of how it is being made human readable.

Comment: Ok. I see, the binary should be 0x01010101. But if I do x/wt &byte I get:  11110111111110000010111101010101. Where are all the numbers at the beginning coming from? I only want the correct numbers at the end

Comment: That's because you are printing a 32-bit value, where there only is 8 bits that you've defined. The remainder is some stuff that happens to be next to your variable...

Answer (score 1):

> What has happened?

Nothing has happened. It isn't in hex in the array. It is binary in the array. It is hex in the source code. If you want to format it as hex, do so. Nobody is stopping you.